# How to move to home fragment by pressing back button

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, navigation, navigation-drawer

I have created a custom navigation drawer using motion layout in which I have image views, text views and a nav host fragment(fragment container view). The Problem is, When I click any view in my navigation drawer, it opens a fragment but when clicked the back button, it closes the application.

This is my mainactivity.kt file

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val contactus = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.contact_us)
        val drawer = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image8)
        val tandc = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.termsandconditions)
        val motionLayout = findViewById<MotionLayout>(R.id.motion_layout)


        contactus.setOnClickListener {

            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
                replace(R.id.fragmentContainerView2, contact_us_fragment())
                commit()

                motionLayout.transitionToStart()


            }
        }
        drawer.setOnClickListener {

            motionLayout.transitionToEnd()
            motionLayout.transitionToStart()
        }
        tandc.setOnClickListener {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
                replace(R.id.fragmentContainerView2, TandCFragment())
                commit()

                motionLayout.transitionToStart()

            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I Move to home fragment on back button press?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to implement the `onBackPressed()` method. This gets called when the user presses / swipes back.

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    // Code here to handle going to fragment
}
```

Comment: I know that I should call onBackPressed() function but I dont know how to write the code for it, so that it land me on the home fragment.
Can you please explain me with a example.

Comment: @MalladiVivekChaitanya What have you tried?

Comment: After So much searching, I tried the below code and it worked for me.

    `override fun onBackPressed() {
        val currentFragment =this.supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainerView2)
        if(currentFragment is contact_us_fragment || currentFragment is TandCFragment){
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
                replace(R.id.fragmentContainerView2, MainscreenFragment())
                commit()}
            }else{
        super.onBackPressed()}
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You can add fragment to back stack and give them id, and then pop the back stack with this id.

```
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .add(yourFragment);
    .addToBackStack("YourFragmentTag");
    .commit()
```

And then pop the stack to this fragment by

```
 override fun onBackPressed() { 
    getFragmentManager().popBackStack("YourFragmentTag", 0);
 }
```

Comment: Thank You SO MUCH
The code I was using was crashing at some points. This Works Perfectly.  I'm new to android development, can you please explain, why have you added the number '0' ?

Comment: Hi, you can read this
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager
(Look for popBackStack)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44655586/difference-between-popbackstackimmediate-vs-popbackstack
In this answer you can see the different between '0' or POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE